# Concatenation of strings in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I'm having issues with the following bash script trying to parse a version number from a WordPress readme file.

```
cat readme.txt | {
    while read -r a b c d; do
    if [ ${a} == "Stable" ]  && [ ${b} == "tag:" ]; then
        VERSION="$c"
    fi
done
out="Updated to version $VERSION thanks"
echo $out
}
```

The output I expect is

```
Updated to version 1.15 thanks
```

but the actual output is

```
 thanks to version 1.15
```

as though the 'thanks' is replacing the front of the string, not being appended to the end. Any clues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`readme.txt` and/or your script has DOS line endings; the value of `VERSION` has a trailing carriage return which affects the output.

Comment: It must be the file; if it were the script he would be getting syntax errors.

Comment: Ah, right. I couldn't see how `$c` could get a carriage return from the file, but that just requires a line with only 3 fields so that `d` isn't set.

Comment: Thanks modified code is VERSION=$(echo $c|tr -d '\n')

Answer (score 1):

If you pipe the output to `cat -A` you will likely find out that `$VERSION` contains a carriage return.

You can get rid of the CRs with `tr`:

```
$ echo $'foo\rb'
boo
$ echo $'foo\rb' | tr -d '\r'
foob
```